# How to add attention layer to seq2seq model on Keras

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, keras, lstm, attention-model

Based on [this](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) article, I wrote this model:

```
enc_in=Input(shape=(None,in_alphabet_len))
lstm=LSTM(lstm_dim,return_sequences=True,return_state=True,use_bias=False)
enc_out,h,c=lstm(enc_in)
dec_in=Input(shape=(None,in_alphabet_len))
decoder,_,_=LSTM(decoder_dim,return_sequences=True,return_state=True)(dec_in,initial_state=[h,c])
decoder=Dense(units=in_alphabet_len,activation='softmax')(decoder)
model=Model([enc_in,dec_in],decoder)
```

How can I add attention layer to this model before decoder?

Comment: here a simple way to add attention: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62949137/10375049

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this repo](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-self-attention),

1. you will need to  `pip install keras-self-attention`
2. import layer `from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention`

   - if you want to use tf.keras not keras, add the following before the import `os.environ['TF_KERAS'] = '1'`
   - Make sure if you are using keras to omit the previous flag as it will cause inconsistencies
3. Since you are using keras functional API,

   ```
   enc_out, h, c = lstm()(enc_in)
   att = SeqSelfAttention()(enc_out)
   dec_in = Input(shape=(None, in_alphabet_len))(att)
   ```

   I hope this answers your question, and future readers

Comment: Well this is self attention. Yet, for seq2seq you will normally want to have attention between encoder and decoder states.

Comment: So, what do you suggest?

Comment: I don't know if there is a Keras wrapper for Bahdanau or Luong attention,  yet there is a neat TensorFlow 2.0 tutorial for seq2seq translation with attention. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention