# How to Change the "Layer" structure because of the version incompatibility in Keras and Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, attention-model

I have a the code for an `Attention Layer` which works smoothly with the `tensorflow==1.9.0-rc0` and `keras==2.2.0` but throws an error that `name has multiple arguments` when I use it with `tensorflow 2.2` and `keras=2.4`.

Please help me change the structure of the `Attention Layer`:

```
class Attention(Layer):
    '''
    Implement Attention is all you need's Bhadanau's style Attention
    '''
    def __init__(self, step_dim,
                 W_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None,
                 W_constraint=None, b_constraint=None,
                 bias=True, **kwargs):
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.init = initializers.get('glorot_uniform')
        self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
        self.b_regularizer = regularizers.get(b_regularizer)
        self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
        self.b_constraint = constraints.get(b_constraint)
        self.bias = bias
        self.step_dim = step_dim
        self.features_dim = 0
        super(Attention, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3
        self.W = self.add_weight((input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 name='{}_W'.format(self.name),
                                 regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.W_constraint)
        self.features_dim = input_shape[-1]
        if self.bias:
            self.b = self.add_weight((input_shape[1],),
                                     initializer='zero',
                                     name='{}_b'.format(self.name),
                                     regularizer=self.b_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.b_constraint)
        else:
            self.b = None
        self.built = True

    def compute_mask(self, input, input_mask=None):
        return None

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        features_dim = self.features_dim
        step_dim = self.step_dim
        eij = K.reshape(K.dot(K.reshape(x, (-1, features_dim)), K.reshape(self.W, (features_dim, 1))), (-1, step_dim))
        if self.bias:
            eij += self.b
        eij = K.tanh(eij)
        a = K.exp(eij)
        if mask is not None:
            a *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
        a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
        a = K.expand_dims(a)
        weighted_input = x * a
        return K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0],  self.features_dim
```

COde for this is imported from [this kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/hengzheng/news-category-classifier-val-acc-0-65) and the original idea is imported from [this user notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/qqgeogor/keras-lstm-attention-glove840b-lb-0-043/code).

I also tried to implement a different version of Attention but it does not take `maxlen` into account.

**Second Attention**

```
class Attention(Layer):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Attention,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self,input_shape):
        self.W=self.add_weight(name="att_weight",shape=(input_shape[-1],1),initializer="normal")
        self.b=self.add_weight(name="att_bias",shape=(input_shape[1],1),initializer="zeros")        
        super(Attention, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self,x):
        et=K.squeeze(K.tanh(K.dot(x,self.W)+self.b),axis=-1)
        at=K.softmax(et)
        at=K.expand_dims(at,axis=-1)
        output=x*at
        return K.sum(output,axis=1)

    def compute_output_shape(self,input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0],input_shape[-1])

    def get_config(self):
        return super(Attention,self).get_config()
```

Comment: your second attention layer it's implemented here without problems in TF 2.2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948332/how-to-add-attention-layer-to-a-bi-lstm/62949137#62949137

Comment: Yes, but how can add the `max_len` argument in my second Attention Layer?

Comment: what's the meaning of maxlen in your first layer?

Comment: Maximum length of the sentences for padding purposes in the Glove Embeddings. I just copied the code. I know theoratically the working Attention layer but unable to formulate one that is why I am unable to change it.

Comment: max_len/step_dim seems to simply be the length of your input (len of the sequence in case of NLP). you need to pass it or rewrite the layer to automatically take account of it

Comment: Could you please the code for the second layer so that it takes that into account. Sorry, I have no expertise on this one. Just started it.

Comment: Also could you please describe what is the difference between the first and the second layer? Are they same?

Comment: the second layer doesn't need this. maxlen is a useless param (still in the first layer u can override it and rewrite the layer better). the layers are different in the way they calculate attention. the first is the Bhadanau's style Attention while in the second the attention is calculated with softmax

Comment: You mean to say that second is `self-attention` as used in transformers and the first one is `Bhadanau's style`  ??

Comment: in a similar way but without the concept of query and key

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks a lot