# attention function in keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am following the self attention in Keras in the following link [How to add attention layer to a Bi-LSTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948332/how-to-add-attention-layer-to-a-bi-lstm/62949137#62949137)

can some one explain that what exactly this attention function is doing here?
I am new to python , what does the shape=(input_shape[-1],1 means?
in which direction we are calculating attention? is it in the direction of batch size?

```
class attention(Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, return_sequences=True):
        self.return_sequences = return_sequences
        super(attention,self).__init__()
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        
        self.W=self.add_weight(name="att_weight", shape=(input_shape[-1],1),
                               initializer="normal")
        self.b=self.add_weight(name="att_bias", shape=(input_shape[1],1),
                               initializer="zeros")
        
        super(attention,self).build(input_shape)
        
    def call(self, x):
        
        e = K.tanh(K.dot(x,self.W)+self.b)
        a = K.softmax(e, axis=1)
        output = x*a
        
        if self.return_sequences:
            return output
        
        return K.sum(output, axis=1)
```

Comment: it's very similar to what presented here: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/11/comprehensive-guide-attention-mechanism-deep-learning/

Comment: thank you in this implementation  def call(self,x):
        et=K.squeeze(K.tanh(K.dot(x,self.W)+self.b),axis=-1)
        at=K.softmax(et)
        at=K.expand_dims(at,axis=-1)
        output=x*at
        return K.sum(output,axis=1)

Comment: but in your implementation, there is tang and softmax in def call , can you please explain , what is the difference? with the call function in the link that you provided?