# Keras custom layer function

Tags: keras, nlp

I am following the self attention in Keras in the following link: [How to add attention layer to a Bi-LSTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948332/how-to-add-attention-layer-to-a-bi-lstm/62949137#62949137)

I am new to python , what does the shape=(input_shape[-1],1) in self.add_weight and shape=(input_shape[1],1) in bias means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape argument sets the expected input dimensions which the model will be fed. In your case, it is just going to be whatever the last dimension of the input shape is for the weight layer and the second dimension of the input shape for the bias layer.

Neural networks take in inputs of fixed size so while building a model, it is important that you hard code the input dimensions for each layer.

Comment: thank you but why second dimension of the input shape for the bias layer.?

Comment: Simply because the dimensions of the bias layer are the same as the output of the weight layer. Think softmax(WX + b)